# How to profile MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, profiling, database-tuning

How do I profile a MySQL database. I want to see all the SQL being run against a database.

I know you can do this:

- `set profiling=1;`
- Run your slow query (eg `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE fromaddress='xxx';`
- `SHOW PROFILES;`

But this seem to only apply to stuff run on the command line, I want to see the results from running a website.

Comment: Obviously, nothing prevents you from running those queries in a web site. I guess you're asking for a method that doesn't imply modifications in the application code.

Comment: ["'SHOW PROFILES' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use Performance Schema instead."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-profiles.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the [query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) - but obviously doing this on a heavy production server could be... unwise.

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me on Ubuntu.

Find and open your MySQL configuration file, usually `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Ubuntu. Look for the section that says “Logging and Replication”

```
# * Logging and Replication
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.

log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

or in newer versions of mysql, comment OUT this lines of codes

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Just uncomment the `log` variable to turn on logging. Restart MySQL with this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Now we’re ready to start monitoring the queries as they come in. Open up a new terminal and run this command to scroll the log file, adjusting the path if necessary.

```
tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial product

http://www.webyog.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the query log in real time.  If on linux, you can use tail -f to see the log live

Also, you can try some free software from these guys:

http://hackmysql.com/mysqlsla

Answer (score 0):

MySqlAdministrator have some useful build in features (including logs view), but for logs it have to be run on same machine as database