# how to measure query execution time in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have doubt about how to calculate execution time of a query.I have ran one select command,after execution it displaying

```
39999 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

Can i treat "0.09 sec" is execution time of my select query or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to profile MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012887/how-to-profile-mysql)

Comment: Most likely, it's the sum of query execution plus row retrieval.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275107/447489 You can see where exactly MySQL spent how much time while processing your query.

Comment: in the above 0.09 sec is very less time but while displaying 39999 records on my mysql screen it showing very large time compare to my current time,how can i treat this time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring actual MySQL query time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274892/measuring-actual-mysql-query-time)

Answer (score 0):

Yes 0.09 sec is the total query execution time. Are you trying to display the whole 3999 records? Writing to console this much records and network time might be longer