# Mysql slow query log, is there a way to enable which php script perform a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to google it, but found no solution for a question which must typical when you try analyzing CMS behavior in your web site. 
I have many scripts working on cron and working web-site, all of them generate queries automatically, some of them are really tough for MySQL. 
I enabled slow queries log but it is unclear which script generates some of queries mysql performs. Is there a way to make it log $_SERVER variables or at least the way script which made that query was called?

Comment: Search terms should include "profiling". Try this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012887/how-to-profile-mysql

Comment: @Used_By_Already perhaps I don't get the idea of profiling you suggested, but I already have logging enabled, there is also saying that 'SHOW PROFILES' is depreciated. I look for a way to add to slow queries log information about which script was the first called and then made that query in result.